# LogStash Docker just stops after start

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

Here is a simple Docker file and configuration file for Elastic Search and Log stash. The plugin wont start

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ulimits:
        memlock:
          soft: -1
          hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/Users/Assets/ELK/data
    ports:
    - 9200:9200
    - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - esnet
  logstash:
      image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.4.0
      container_name: logstash
      environment:
        - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      links:
       - elasticsearch
      volumes:
        - /Users/Assets/ELK/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
      depends_on: 
        - elasticsearch
      networks:
          - esnet 
volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet
```

And the configuration file is  as below

```
input { stdin { } }
    output {
      elasticsearch { hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"] }
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
```

And the container just exits on start. No error message and i am pretty new to the stack so any help is appreciated.

logstash         | [2019-11-13T22:39:50,107][INFO ][logstash.agent

> ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main],
>   :non_running_pipelines=>[]} elasticsearch    | {"type": "server",
>   "timestamp": "2019-11-13T22:39:50,113Z", "level": "INFO", "component":
>   "o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService", "cluster.name":
>   "docker-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch", "message": "adding
>   template [logstash] for index patterns [logstash-*]", "cluster.uuid":
>   "85h4uyuJQPKbTqOoflh_WA", "node.id": "qt3cb4TBR9yHUsBk3tQ8cg"  }
>   logstash         | [2019-11-13T22:39:50,198][INFO
>   ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Creating rollover alias
>    elasticsearch    | {"type": "server",
>   "timestamp": "2019-11-13T22:39:50,251Z", "level": "INFO", "component":
>   "o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService", "cluster.name":
>   "docker-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch", "message":
>   "[logstash-2019.11.13-000001] creating index, cause [api], templates
>   [logstash], shards [1]/[1], mappings [_doc]", "cluster.uuid":
>   "85h4uyuJQPKbTqOoflh_WA", "node.id": "qt3cb4TBR9yHUsBk3tQ8cg"  }
>   logstash         | [2019-11-13T22:39:50,612][INFO ][logstash.agent
>   ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600} logstash
>   | [2019-11-13T22:39:50,750][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
>   Installing ILM policy
>   {"policy"=>{"phases"=>{"hot"=>{"actions"=>{"rollover"=>{"max_size"=>"50gb",
>   "max_age"=>"30d"}}}}}} to _ilm/policy/logstash-policy elasticsearch
>   | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-11-13T22:39:50,771Z", "level":
>   "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.i.a.TransportPutLifecycleAction",
>   "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch",
>   "message": "adding index lifecycle policy [logstash-policy]",
>   "cluster.uuid": "85h4uyuJQPKbTqOoflh_WA", "node.id":
>   "qt3cb4TBR9yHUsBk3tQ8cg"  } logstash         |
>   [2019-11-13T22:39:52,258][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash
>   shut down.

Comment: Simply logstash hasn't any input in stdin { }

Comment: Isin't supposed to wait for an input? aint that the whole point of this plugin ?. What am i missing ?

Comment: The `stdin` input plugin reads events from the standard input of the system, it is used mostly in situations where you run logstash in the cli, sending the output of a command as the input for logstash, for example `cat file.log | logstash -f pipeline.conf`. You will need another [input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html) based on what you want to do.